# How to apply dimensionality reduction to a data set with outliers?

Tags: outliers, dimensionality-reduction, extreme-value, data-preprocessing

I try to apply dimensionality reduction to a multidimensional data set (with numerical features) with significant outliers. I have managed to identify outliers with Isolation Forest but now I'm in a quandary how to handle them:

- As the features are on a different scale, I'm expected to do some
  normalization as a first step, but having these strong outliers usual
  methods like PCA are out of question as they're usually sensitive to
  outliers.
- Omitting the observation seems suboptimal as it increases
  bias and anyway, I'm going to work on a time series forecasting later
  on where each time step is expected to be filled in the given
  interval, I cannot leave out observations.
- Maybe I could do clipping/winsorizing on the individual features but
  I'm vary of this as it disregards feature correlation.

Is there a good way in this situation? Maybe any dimensionality reduction method which is robust to outliers?